# Double spaces in paragraphs for publishers?

Tags: publishing

I was once told by a former writing partner of mine that publishers require paragraphs in stories to be separated by double spaces to be submitted.

Is that tidbit true?

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly. ***All*** lines should be double spaced. Editors (and other professional readers of submissions) will use the space for hand-written notes or corrections. I believe most editors still print and read from paper with hand-written notes, it is the most convenient form and works pretty much anywhere, without batteries or electricity, and it is simple to leaf through and otherwise mechanically manage (dog ear pages, add paper clips or post-it tabs, etc).